# Not able to use if statement with dompdf

Tags: php, html, if-statement, syntax, dompdf

This is my code:

```
<?php
$root = realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);
include "$root/config.php";
require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';
use Dompdf\Dompdf;
$dompdf = new Dompdf();

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT name FROM my_table');
$stmt->execute();

$results = $stmt->fetchAll();
foreach( $results as $row ) {
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();

$html = "

".if(!empty($row['name']))  {
echo "My name is".$row['name']."";
}."

";

$dompdf->load_html($html);
}
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream();
?>
```

I'm always getting:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in
>   /var/www/user_name/html/create_pdf.php on line 17

Simple HTML code like this `$html = "<p>Hello, it's me!</p>";` works.

Also PHP code like this `$html = "My name is ".$row['name']."!";` works.

Just the if-statement seems not to work.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't concatenate strings with `if` in the middle (because the `if` statment doesn't return anything).

You can solve this by using the ternary operator:

```
$html = "
    ".(!empty($row['name']) ? "My name is".$row['name'] : '')."
";
```

In case you have long if-else statements you should close the string and concatenate it inside:

```
$html = "";
$html .= "Some string\n";
if (....) {
    $html .= "Something new\n";
} elseif (...) {
    $html .= "more...\n";
} else {
    $html .= "...\n";
}
$html .= "Some text\";
```

Comment: Thanks it's working. But, what if I have (big) if-else-statements or so. Is there a more elegant solution for it?

Answer (score 1):

```
$html = "text... " . (!empty($row['...'])) ? $row['...'] : " " . " more text...";
```

Remove the if and create an 'inline' or ternary expression like above.

If statements cannot be concatenated unless a shorthand expression is used (ie: ternary)

In your case, this should work:

```
$html = " " . (!empty($row['name'])) ? "Your name is " . $row['name'] : "" . " ";
```

For longer concatenation, you can do this (and readability):

```
$html = "";
$html .= (expression) ? True : False;
$html .= "";
```

To concatenate we use `.=` in PHP.

I'd suggest using the `print_f()` method in PHP for long HTML, something like.

```
print_f("your name is %s", (!empty($row['name'])) ? $row['name'] : 'Default');
```

Comment: Thanks it's working. But, what if I have (big) if-else-statements or so. Is there a more elegant solution for it?

Comment: Yes, I'll update my answer for you now regarding that @David

Comment: Got a vote from me (beat me be less than a minute I think ;) )

Comment: Haha reputation ent my goal anyway ;) nice answer though @Dekel

Comment: Reputation is always the goal ;)

Comment: Feel free to add my Skype if you like creating custom MVC's and portals @Dekel its: kaydotm8